# How can I use Drag handlers (IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IDragHandler) with a 2D sprite renderer instead of a UI Image?

Tags: unity, sprites, unity-ui

In my game, I assigned all of the blocks to be 2D sprites so that they could be easily converted into prefabs:
[image]

However, when designing the drag and drop scripts, I noticed that all of the drag and drop handlers such as IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IDragHandler, etc. weren't working at all. I later noticed that these were intended to be used by UI Images.

Now I am left wondering what I can do to make these 2D Sprites be usable by these functions for UI Images. Do I have any other options other than to start from scratch by making new UI Images?

Here's the small amount of code needed to create a reproducible example:

```
Public class DragDrop : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IDragHandler
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Canvas canvas;
    private CanvasGroup canvasGroup;

    private RectTransform rectTransform;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        canvasGroup = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        canvasGroup.alpha = 0.6f;
        canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = false;
    }
    
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta / canvas.scaleFactor;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        canvasGroup.alpha = 1f;
        canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that:

1. You have a `Collider2D`(`BoxCollider2D` etc.) added.
2. `Physics2DRaycaster` added to your camera.
3. `EventSystem` in your scene.
4. Nothing is blocking the `Raycast` to this `SpriteRenderer`.

---

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider2D))]
public class DraggableSpriteRenderer : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _spriteRenderer;
    public SpriteRenderer _SpriteRenderer => this._spriteRenderer;

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnDrag");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(
            x: eventData.delta.x * Time.deltaTime,
            y: eventData.delta.y * Time.deltaTime
        );

        this.transform.localPosition += movement;
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnBeginDrag");
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnEndDrag");
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    private void Reset()
    {
        this._spriteRenderer = this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }
#endif
}
```

[image: IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler]

Comment: How can a raycast be blocked?

Comment: @kayrayorulmaz have you tried all of the steps before this? It can be blocked if there are objects in  front of it that also receive raycast hit.

Comment: I have placed all of the intractable objects on layer 1, which is a layer higher than any other object in the scene. However, the blocks still don't move at all. All of the previous steps have also been taken.

Comment: @kayrayorulmaz do you have `SpriteRenderer`s inside `Canvas`? I am trying to reproduce this scenario.

Comment: @kayrayorulmaz I have tried to recreate it, so there are 3 scenarios. 1. It's just an object with `Transform` - works fine. 2. It's an object with `Transform` but inside `Canvas` - works fine. 3. It's a `SpriteRenderer` with `RectTransform` inside `Canvas` - it doesn't draw anything because `Canvas` doesn't recognise `SpriteRenderer`. After adding `Image` - works fine. I have posted an edit with my code that I have used for testing this.